# Floating action menu inside another floating action menu

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to add a floating action menu inside another floating action menu.i want my parent floating action menu from down to up and sub floating action menu from right to left direction.I tried using libraries but no library support is supporting this functionality. can anyone help me.

below is image of what i am trying to get

[image]

Comment: Try this lib https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton, It is easy to use

Comment: i tried using that library but i am not able to implement a menu inside another menu.

Comment: A representation of what you want will be helpfull

Comment: can you show an image of your expected result.

Comment: sure, will share

Comment: @ManojPerumarath  i have attached the image. please help me.

Comment: @RakshitNawani  i have attached the image. please help me.

Comment: @AmruthaSaj check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100635/7666442 make some changes as per your requirement i think this will help you

Comment: @NileshRathod so the only way is to create custom layout and handle visibility?

Comment: @AmruthaSaj may be because you need to create your own custom view's for your requirement let me know if any help required

Answer (score 2):

No library supports this functionality because it goes against [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions).

> Don’t put overflow menus in the floating action button actions. There should be at most two taps from the initial screen to get to the intended destination.

I would suggest you rethink the design, remember a floating action button must transform into **related** actions. You could move it so you have two floating action buttons, or move the secondary menu to an overflow menu.

Answer (score 1):

> If you dont want to use library , than you can try this using a custom
>   layout and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardCornerRadius"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardElevation"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fab1_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bookmark category"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cardview_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardview_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cardview_vertical_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/cardview_vertical_padding" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardCornerRadius"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardElevation"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fab2_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add post "
            android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cardview_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardview_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cardview_vertical_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/cardview_vertical_padding" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutFabSettings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSetting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> And in your class file you can use

```
     private FloatingActionButton fabSettings;
        private LinearLayout fab1;
        private LinearLayout fab2;

 fabSettings = this.findViewById(R.id.fabSetting);
    fab1 = this.findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab2 = this.findViewById(R.id.fab2);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    //When main Fab (Settings) is clicked, it expands if not expanded already.
    //Collapses if main FAB was open already.
    //This gives FAB (Settings) open/close behavior
    fabSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fabExpanded == true){
                closeSubMenusFab();
            } else {
                openSubMenusFab();
            }
        }
    });

    //Only main FAB is visible in the beginning
    closeSubMenusFab();

 //closes FAB submenus
    private void closeSubMenusFab(){
        fab1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fab2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        fabSettings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp);
        fabExpanded = false;
    }

    //Opens FAB submenus
    private void openSubMenusFab(){
        fab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Change settings icon to 'X' icon
        fabSettings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
        fabExpanded = true;
    }
```

> It looks like this

[image]

Comment: You can make layout as per your requirement , and as you have mentioned above same design could be made ,using the above method , and you can also add animation on it to look more attractive

Answer (score 1):

Tha layout  file is

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".FloatingActivity">




<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"

    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your activity,

```
  private FloatingActionButton fab, fab1,  fab3;
private boolean isFABOpen = false;
private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;
private boolean isfab3Open = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_floating);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab1 = findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab3 = findViewById(R.id.fab3);
    fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
    fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
    rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_forward);
    rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_backward);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            animateFAB();
        }
       });
       fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            animateFab3();
        }
    });
   }

     private void animateFab3() {
       if (isfab3Open) {
        //  fab1.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab3.setClickable(false);
        isfab3Open = false;
      } else {
     //   fab1.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab3.setClickable(true);
        isfab3Open = true;
    }
   }

     public void animateFAB() {

    if (isFABOpen) {

        fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
        fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
        fab1.setClickable(false);
        isFABOpen = false;

    } else {

        fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        fab1.startAnimation(fab_open);
        fab1.setClickable(true);
        isFABOpen = true;

    }    }   }
```

And the animations are,
fab_close.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="0.8"
    android:fromYScale="0.8"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="300"/>
  </set>
```

fab_open

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.8"
    android:toYScale="0.8" />
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
 </set>
```

rotate_backward

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="300"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

rotate_forward

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="45"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="300"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
    </set>
```

Comment: let me try your answer

Comment: i tried your code but. the issue is i want the fabclose animation to be translate down towards the fab button. is there any way to do so?

Comment: fab1.animate().translationY(-getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_55)); here you have to specify the height to jump in dimens.xml